# Yii2 json_encode Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to signup, after i made a composer update for Yii2 and I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument
```

The error is where the model attributes array is encoded as a json:

```
Json::encode($this->owner->attributes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

Do you by any chance have diacritics in the attributes of the model? You might need to transform them to UTF-8 before you encode them.